# Node api precision lost while reading numeric data from database

Tags: node.js, api

We have node js <strike>api</strike> connected to Sql server with mssql package.When we try to read numeric data using SP, it returns without precision.But when I try to run same in SSMS it returns correct data.
For eg. 1.000 returns as 1
Some issue also for big numbers that it rounds up last 3 digits data 
while reading using api.
For eg.- 71222234565709 returns as  71222234565700

Comment: use parseFloat() in your api, then return response. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

Comment: That data is returning from SP. so no single field there to apply parseFloat. Data returns in recordsets in json format

Comment: can you post your response and codes ?

Comment: Response-"recordsets": [
        [ {
                "SRNO": "1",
                "ENTITY": 2,
                "REQUISITIONNO": "RE201700390",
                "ITM_CODE": "100005310",
                "ITM_DESC": "REFILING TONER ",
                "UM": "NO",
                "QTY": 1,
                "NI_IND_ITEMCD": "100005310",
                "AVAIL_QTY": 0,
                "TRANS_QTY": "",
                "ACCOUNT": "0",
                "PURPOSE": "Department Use",
                "TOLOCQTY": 85
            }]
    ],
    "returnValue": 0
}--Here QTY should be 1.000

Comment: can you post it in your question and explain where you are getting error

Comment: Code- function NI_INV_REQMATERIAL_TRANS_SET_VALUES(request,response,next){    
            var jsondata = request.body;
            poolg.request()  
    .input('p_1ID', sql.VarChar(500), jsondata['p_1ID'])
.input('p_2', sql.VarChar(500), jsondata['p_2'])
.input('p_3', sql.VarChar(500), jsondata['p_3'])
.input('p_4', sql.VarChar(500), jsondata['p_4'])
.execute('dbo.spname', (err, result) => {  if(err) {   response.send(err);
     }
     else  if(result)
     {
       response.send(result);
     }})}

Comment: 1st check the link then post the question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you are awesome man @HamidKhan